# sphinx don't catch dockstrings

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

i trying to make a doc by using sphinx

i use `sphinx-apidoc -f -o source/ ../`
and then `make html`
it created for me documentation but this doc don't include dockstrings from files

i use same dockstrings:

```
def send_confirm_msg(self, token, email, legal_type):
    """
    Отсылает письмо с потверждением
    :param token: токен потверждения
    :param email: емаил на который придёт ссылка
    :return: None
    """
```

my conf

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/config

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/projects/gh_project/'))
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/projects/gh_project/package'))
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/projects/gh_project/api_middleman/app'))
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/projects/gh_project/api_middleman/db_create'))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'MIS'
copyright = '2019, ICode'
author = 'ICode'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '0.0.0.1'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc']

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
#
# This is also used if you do content translation via gettext catalogs.
# Usually you set "language" from the command line for these cases.
language = 'ru'

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'agogo'

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = []

html_show_copyright = False
html_show_sphinx = False
```

in rst

```
gh\_project.api\_legal.app.views module
---------------------------------------

.. automodule:: gh_project.api_legal.app.views
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

api\_middleman.logger\_conf module
----------------------------------

.. automodule:: api_middleman.logger_conf
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

but in result i see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJOC3.jpg without any dockstrings it don't caching any dockstrings how to solve this problems
all dockstrings i use in def functions maybe problem with it?

Comment: i try to add sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/projects/dev/gh_project/')) but it didn't help me

Comment: You should point to the directory above the package. If the package is `gh_project`, then you need `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/projects/dev'))`.

Comment: i add in both cases i recive reading sources... [100%] api_middleman.app                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'logger_conf' from module 'api_middleman'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'api_middleman'

Comment: my files are located in /home/projects/dev/gh_project/api_middleman/

Comment: Then what is `api_legal`? In the RST you have `.. automodule:: gh_project.api_legal.app.views`.

Comment: oh sry it the same folder like api_middleman i was try to do same with api_legal too settings same for api_middleman
api\_middleman.logger\_conf module
----------------------------------

.. automodule:: api_middleman.logger_conf
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

Comment: i try to sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../gh_project'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/projects/dev/gh_project'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/projects/dev/gh_project/api_middleman'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/projects/dev/gh_project/api_middleman/app'))


but receive  WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'logger_conf' from module 'api_middleman'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'api_middleman'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in conf.py 
it was necessary to add `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))`